# Explain to me what these constructors are doing in this program?

Tags: java, constructor

I just learned about constructors and had to use them in a recent program. I got it right however I still do not understand exactly what they do. If someone could give me a detailed explanation using this program as reference that would be great!

**MAIN CLASS**

```
public class Student 
{

public static void main(String[]args)
{

    String question, name, GPAStr, studentNumberStr;
    int studentNumber;
    double GPA;

    question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to see if you Qualify for the Dean's List? (Y or N)");

    while (question.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    {
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your name.");

        studentNumberStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your student number.");
        studentNumber = Integer.parseInt(studentNumberStr);

        GPAStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your GPA.");
        GPA = Double.parseDouble(GPAStr);

        StudentIO students = new StudentIO(name, GPA);

        // ouput

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, students.getDeansList());

        question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to see if you Qualify for the Dean's List? (Y or N)");

        if (question.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            //display the content of players processed

        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,StudentIO.getCount());
        }
    }
}
}
```

**SECOND CLASS(THE ONE WITH CONSTRUCTORS THEY ARE LABELED)**

```
public class StudentIO 
{

//instance fields

    private String name;
    private double GPA;

    // static fields

    private static final double GPAMIN=3.0;
    private static int count = 0;

    public StudentIO(String theName, double theGPA)  // constructor
    {
        name = theName;
        GPA= theGPA;

        count = count +1;
    }

    public StudentIO()    //no arg constructor
    {
        name = " ";
        GPA = 0;

        count = count +1;
    }

    public void setName(String theName)
    {
        name = theName;
    }

    public void setGPA(double theGPA)
    {
        GPA = theGPA;
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public double getGPA()
    {
        return GPA;
    }

    public String getDeansList()
    {
        if(GPA >= GPAMIN)
            return (name + ", has made the Dean's List!");
        else
            return(name + ", did not make the Dean's List!");

    }

    public static String getCount()
    {
        return ("You processed " + count + "students.");
    }
}
```

Comment: These are very straightforward constructors.  What is it you don't understand?  Do you understand objects?

Comment: Is the first one used when the person enters yes and the second one when the person enter no so that each time it goes through the loop it still adds 1 to count?

Comment: I think @imanis_tn explains it pretty well.  In the posted code, the "first" constructor (the one that accepts arguments) is the only one that is ever called.

Answer (score 1):

```
StudentIO students = new StudentIO(name, GPA);
```

Will create a StudentIO object called students, and affect name and GPA parameters to your object created by using the first contractor:

```
 public StudentIO(String theName, double theGPA)  // constructor
    {
        name = theName;
        GPA= theGPA;

        count = count +1;
    }
```

And that is equivalent to call :

```
StudentIO students = new StudentIO();
students.setName(name);
students.setGPA(GPA);
```

which will use the seconde contractor :

```
public StudentIO()    //no arg constructor
{
    name = " ";
    GPA = 0;

    count = count +1;
}
```

with the two methods

```
public void setName(String theName)
{
    name = theName;
}

public void setGPA(double theGPA)
{
    GPA = theGPA;
}
```

Finaly, the two approach give you the same result, its a style matter, and some times we are forced to use the seconds one in a strong coupled objects.

Comment: Okay the no arg is still giving me some conceptual trouble. Why is it necessary to have in the code?

Answer (score 0):

> count = count +1;

It seems you are referring to this line in the constructors. The variable `count` is a static member in `StudentIO` class and is being used to keep track of number of StudentIO objects created using the parameterized or default constructor.

Comment: when will it decide which constructor to use?

Comment: Depends on what is called by the user of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The construct instances of the `StudentIO` class. Their purpose is to set initial state for the new instance(s) of `StudentIO`. Each instance has its' own state. Static variables are shared among instances, so on each construction you're adding one to a count. It'll tell you how many instance(s) have been created (I guess).